# SQL statement with multiple subqueries (as separate fields in same recordset)

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I am trying to create SQL statement for a DataSet (in SSRS) that selects the sum of a field - grouped at different date ranges within the table - and make them separate "fields" available for my Tablix. I'm not even sure if it is possible, but am looking to do this all in a SQL solution if possible.
So, my example is - 1 table that holds the dates and payments made.
I need to select all records from the past 3 years, and separate them into 3 columns of totals - by year. So, I would sum up all of the records for each year - as a column.

Is this even possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please go to this [site](https://dbfiddle.uk) and construct a fiddle with some sample data and your desired result. Post this at the bottom of the question also. It **seems** to me that you're looking for some sort of window function - you might want to check the documentation on these? Notify me that you have done so by putting `@` and my handle `Vérace` (no space) in a comment beneath this one - always add supplementary information to the **question** and not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) your query. You haven't posted a schema, but something like this:

```
SELECT [2020],[2021],[2022] 
  FROM (SELECT YEAR([payment_date]) AS [year], [value]
          FROM [payments]) AS src  
 PIVOT  
 (  
    SUM([value])  
    FOR [year] IN ([2020],[2021],[2022])
 ) AS x;
```

Example: [sqlfiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=4acecfcb-260c-4495-8572-1ed7a61f03f2)

Comment: BOOM! goes the dynamite! Thank you Mr. Brownstone! That worked perfect! "Keep Knockin'!"